# Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, radon-nikodym

Please how to find the Lebesgue decomposition of $\nu$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure $m$ where $\nu$ is the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure associated to the following function:
$$ F(x) = \begin{cases}0 &\text{if }x < 0\,,\\ 2x&\text{if }0 \leq x < 1\,,\\2&\text{if }x \geq 1\,.\end{cases}$$

Thank you very much

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to express $\nu$ as a sum of the lebesgue measure $m$ and another measure but  I got stack.

Answer (score 1):

If $\nu$ is the one dimensional Lebesgue measure and the $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$, then the Radon-Nikodym derivative $\frac{d\mu}{d\nu}$ is just $\frac{dF}{dx}$ where $F(x)=\mu([a,x])$ for $x>a$ and $-\mu([x,a])$ for $x<a$. Here $a$ is any fixed constant. (In the case where $\mu$ is finite it is often convenient to use $(-\infty,x]$ instead.) Try to prove this in general before applying it to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

$d\nu (x)=f(x)dm(x)$ where $f(x)=2$ for $0<x<1$ and $0$ for all other $x$. (The measure is absolutely continuous). [Singular part is $0$].

Comment: what is I(0, 1 ) (x) ? please

Comment: @Tom I have written it out explicitly now.

Comment: please could you give more details why you got this answer ? thank you

Comment: @Tom Note that $F'$ is the function $f$ I have defined. (There is no derivative at $0$ and $1$ but that doesn't matter). Now just compute the measure whose density (i.e. RND) if $f$. Either this will coincide with $\nu$ or there will a non -zero part in the difference between these (which gives you the singular part). In this case you will find that $f(x)dm(x)$ is nothing but $\nu$ so there is no singular part.